# What am i doing wrong in passing this string to label in a view controller segue (ios)?

Tags: ios, uilabel, uistoryboardsegue

I have a table view controller segueing (with identifier `feedToPollQuerySeg`) to another view controller.
I am trying to print out the index number of the row selected in a label in the latter.

Feed View:

```
@interface FeedController3 : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView* feedTableView;


-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(NSString*)stringNum{
        if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"feedToPollQuerySeg"]){


        PollQueryController *pqc = [[PollQueryController alloc] init];
        pqc = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSLog(@"This is row sending: %@", stringNum);
        pqc.parentRowSelected.text = stringNum;
        }

    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

            NSInteger rowSelected = indexPath.row;
            NSString *stringNum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", rowSelected];
            NSLog(@"This is row selected: %@", stringNum);
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"feedToPollQuerySeg" sender: stringNum];

    }
```

PollQuery View

```
@interface PollQueryController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *parentRowSelected;


@implementation PollQueryController
@synthesize parentRowSelected;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Parent Row Selected: %@", parentRowString);

...
}
```

But the label isn't updating...?

> This is row selected: 1
>     This is row sending: 1
>     Parent Row Selected:

Comment: Here `pqc.parentRowSelected.text = stringNum;`, is `pqc.parentRowSelected ` nil?

Comment: when you tap cell is that log gives value with out null??

Comment: You are performing segue in a strange way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because when you are in `prepareForSegue` of `FeedController3`, `PollQueryController's` view isn't initialized.
Add `NSString` in `PollQueryController` set `NSString` value in `prepareForSegue`.

In `viewWillAppear` of `PollQueryController` assign text to `parentRowSelected` label.

Like This -

In the viewController that will present the another viewController:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqual:@"feedToPollQuerySeg"])
    {
        PollQueryController *pvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        pvc.myString = stringNum;
    }
}
```

And inside the presented viewController:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.parentRowSelected.text = self.myString;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the key, i didnt have the viewWillAppear method and the view hadnt initialized yet.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a neater way to achieve what you want:

`FeedController3.m`:

```
@interface FeedController3

@property (nonatomic) int rowSelected;

@end

@implementation

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     self.rowSelected = indexPath.row;
     NSLog(@"This is row selected: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.rowSelected]);
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"feedToPollQuerySeg" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"feedToPollQuerySeg"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        PollQueryController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        vc.rowSelected = self.rowSelected;
    }
}

@end
```

`PollQueryController.h`:

```
@interface PollQueryController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) int rowSelected;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *parentRowSelected;

@end
```

`PollQueryController.m`:

```
@implementation

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];    
    self.parentRowSelected.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.rowSelected];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thankyou. I actually had it like you had it but without the viewWillAppear method before changing it (after seeing another StackOverflow question which did it that strange way). I think the key here was i didn't have the viewWillAppear method. I will accept Rahul's as answer as he answered first and also answered that the view wasn't initialised, but thankyou as well as your layout was easier for me to comprehend.